# Merging Git Branches

Tags: git, aptana

I have two branches, one is the master, one is 'test.' This name was dual-purpose, I was not only testing the branches, but testing out some changes as well. Now, I have the test branch working great. However, I am not working alone. The master branch is being worked on too. Now, I would love to copy my test branch over to the main. Then, I would love to do a pull and see what changes have been made so I can push the changes.

First, I am using Aptana. I tried the drop-down settings button. I clicked and attempted to merge while on the Master branch with the 'test' branch. This did something, not really sure what. It then said I had a problem. So, now, I ran git mergetool, and again, this did something. It said everything was good.Now, the two branches are both working as they should, however, they are not identical. In fact, they are both exactly what they were before any merge took place.

What can I do to fix this? 'test' is the important branch right now, it has all my work. Master has some important stuff, but not locally. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I would suggest using a terminal when working with Git. It's easy and fun!

Comment: I would recommend that you try to reproduce this problem with a small test repository. Just create a test repo with a few files, make a few commits in each branch, with some conflicts (that is, in both branches modify the same files in the same places), and try merging. If this helps you figure out how it works, great! If not, copy down the exact error messages you see, and write down exactly what you did. Then you can ask a question with enough detail that we might be able to help. As it is, it's hard to tell what your "somethings" are, and thus hard to help.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, commit and push every change in both branches.

Then, checkout to master, and merge test:

```
$git checkout master
$git merge test
```

It should display warning on every file that has a problem with merging. Sometimes Git can't figure out the "right" merge and you have to manually fix it.
Go to those files, check for merge problems (they're easy to guess, Git wraps problems in <<<< ==== >>>>)
And that's it! You have successfully merged test on master. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The Aptana Git integration isn't as mature or advanced as the [EGit one](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) (see [Aptana ticket 1372](https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/1372-preference-for-git-egit-integration)). And it involves having [Git installed and correctly setup first](https://superuser.com/questions/241372/using-git-on-aptana-3-standalone).

[Christopher Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630728/christopher-williams) is working hard on improving the Aptana Git plugin, but in case of problem, going back to a shell session, like [fedeisas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227927/fedeisas)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671967/merging-git-branches/5672288#5672288) illustrates, is the best option.

Comment: git merge Test gives me: Already up-to-date. Sadly, however, it certainly is not.